# How to read returned parameter from RADIUS server

Tags: scripting, tcl, cisco, ivr, cisco-ios

I have configured a Cisco voice gateway to use a Cisco ACS on a windows server 2003. Meanwhile, I have configured an external database through an ODBC connection with a MSSQL server. As mentioned in the TCLIVR document, I have to use a stored procedure on Mirosoft SQL server named CSNTAuthUserPap to respond to authorization request from voice gateway. The stored procedure has the following format:

> CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CSNTAuthUserPap]
>
> @username varchar(64), @pass varchar(255)
>
> AS SET NOCOUNT ON
>
> IF EXISTS(
>
> SELECT  username FROM  users WHERE  username  = @username AND
> Returnparam  = @pass )
>
> SELECT 0,'1','1','No Error'
>
> ELSE
>
> SELECT 3,0,'odbc','ODBC Authen Error'

My question is about reading parameters returned to the ACS server. Th returned record has the following format:

1. Returned result: 0 means auth successfull, 1 to 4 means auth unsucessfull
2. Group Number for authorization
3. Account Information
4. Error String

> How can I read the Account Information returned by ACS in my TCL Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.
The answer lies in the AVPairs and creating custom avpairs. I must specify avpair for each group returned from the radius server and read them in the TCL code like this:

```
    if { [infotag get aaa_avpair_exists h323-ivr-in] } {
        set CustomerStatus [infotag get aaa_avpair h323-ivr-in]
foreach pairs [split $CustomerStatus]  {
                           set value_list [split $pairs :]
                           set key [lindex $value_list 0]
                           set value [lindex $value_list 1]
                           if { $key == "contractType" } {
                                set contractType $value
                           } 
                   }
```